(.0) float in Javascript
I am trying to do write a code for a function that displays a boolean after checking if the value is an integer or not. see my definition of an integer in my ideal outputs below when i call the function:
So far, my code is failing because it generates true for validInteger ( 10.0 ) when i want it to be false. Javascript is struggling because 10.0 = 10
DESIRED OUTPUT
validInteger ( '10' ) // should return True
validInteger ( 10 ) // should return True 
validInteger ( '-10' ) // should return False
validInteger ( -10 ) // should return False
validInteger ( 0.0 ) // should return False
validInteger ( 10.0 ) // should return False
validInteger ( -10.0 ) // should return False

I wonder if anyone has an idea on how i can get a false result for validInteger ( 10.0 ). so far this is the code i have been able to write:
function validInteger (value) { // value can be a string or a number (integer)
  
  const numberValue = Number(value);
  return Number.isInteger(numberValue) && numberValue >= 0 && String(numberValue) ===     String(value);

}


why do you want to do this? In memory in the actual computer while the code is running, it is impossible to tell the difference between 10 and 10.0. The two values are not two values; they are precisely the same, indistinguishable in any way.

Can you explain why you believe that 10.0 is not an integer?  (Also, can you explain why you want False for -10 and '-10'?)

@Pointy it is a uni code assignment. I don't have a real life use case . our tutors want us to be able to crack this through so hoping someone might come up with an idea.

In that case you will have to use string operations, as suggested by @RichardKenneth.  Also you need to know that your tutors are displaying some significant idiocy here, as this is quite a meaningless assignment.

@SteveSummit once again i don't have a real life use case for my function. I am only working on my assignment. my desired output are the tests our  functions we build  will have to pass to receive the highest possible score from our tutors

First convert to a string.  Then, three possibilities: (a) if the string contains a . character, return False.  (b) If the string contains a . or a - character, return False.  (c) If the string contains anything other than the digits 0 - 9, return False.

@SteveSummit the challenge with that idea is once .toString is applied to 10.0, it changes it to 10. the output of the code below is "10" not "10.0"
let a = 10.0
b = a.toString()
console.log(b)

"the challenge with that idea is once .toString is applied to 10.0, it changes it to 10" the "change" happens before you call .toString(). You should only use strings, not numbers if you want this to work. I doubt whoever made the assignment expects you to change how JS handles numbers.

@Lolipop if you start off with a number value (as opposed to a string), then your assignment is hopeless and you cannot complete it.

You should ask your tutor for hints and/or clarification.  There's something fishy about this assignment.  It's not clear it's worth your time trying to solve it (or ours).

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer, all the calls should return true, because 10, 10.0, 0.0, -10 and -10.0 are integers. It's not only JavaScript. It's math: 10.0 = 10. 10.0, 10 and 100/10 are different representations of the same integer value.

10 and 10.0 are the same in JS. It's a primitive value of type number. You cannot distinguish between these notations in runtume.

The JavaScript Number type is a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
You can check only whether an expression is a number and has a decimal part with Number.isInteger().
Also it seems as a XY problem since its purpose isn't clear.
For allocating integers you could examine typed arrays.

I think it would be better to share the actual specification instead of the interpretation from Mozilla: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type. It is more accurate and, well, it is the source of truth.

The solution I see here is to make the function receive the argument as a string.
Something like this.
function validIntegerString(value) { // value must be a string
  return (
    value.length != 0 && !value.includes(".") && Number.isInteger(Number(value))
  );
}


Hi Richard,the challenge with that idea is once .toString is applied to 10.0, it changes it to 10. the output of the code below is "10" not "10.0" let a = 10.0 b = a.toString() console.log(b)

Hi Richard, value can be either a string or a number. when value is '10.0' your code will work as expected but when value is 10.0, code won't work as expected.

@Lolipop, to the best of what i know, what you want to achieve can't be possible with a number input.

i wonder if i can hardcode it in anyway..for example maybe including an if conditional in my function that says something like if the function returns anything with .0 just yield false hahah

I guess javascript would have already removed the trailing zero(s) in a NUMBER value before you use it in your function.

I downvotes because the goal is to return different results for validInteger ( 10 ) and validInteger ( 10.0 ). That's impossible.

@jabaa Your assumption is incorrect.  It's within the realm of possibility that the goal can be satisfied by returning different results for validInteger ( "10" ) and validInteger ( "10.0" ).  That's obviously possible.

@SteveSummit The code snippet in the question contains validInteger ( 10 ) // should return True and validInteger ( 10.0 ) // should return False. That's impossible. This answer completely ignores these two test cases. Yes, it's possible to change the question and the test cases, but that's not a helpful answer.
